# How to Integrate Artifical Neural Networks

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, soft-question, neural-networks

How can one calculate the integral of a neural network?
Is there a better method than writing the output as a function of the input then trying usual integration methods?

Even a (sufficiently good) approximation can suffice in my case, where I am trying to fit complicated high dimensional data sets to neural networks and curve fitting them with it, and I would like to add an integration/differentiation feature.

Should I just use usual methods for numerical integration like Gauss-Legendre or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I am curious about the reason, which might shed some light on how best one can integrate: Why would you like to integrate?  Differentiation can be done, but if you just want to evaluate the derivative you can use "automatic differentiation" that's already implemented in many machine learning frameworks.

Comment: Honestly, the neural network is more for curve fitting, I'm just curious about integration of ANNs, and knowing there is probably no practical application, I want to see how if we can leverage its hierarchical structure to make its integration easier.

Comment: You could use Gauss-Legendre, but you can start with something as simple as Monte-Carlo.